# Automatic alias creation on indexing request in elasticsearch

Tags: indexing, elasticsearch, alias

Is it possible to automatically create an alias on an indexing request for an absent index in elasticsearch instead of creating the index?

For example, let's say an indexing request comes in for the `uk_london` index, with type `document` and the document contents. The `uk_london` index does not exist, so it will be created. I want to avoid this creation, to avoid having a [kagillion shards](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/kagillion-shards.html). What I would like is for ES to create an alias `uk_london` (with routing, filtering etc.) and have it point to the `uk` index (which already exists).

I know this problem is solvable by changing the way the indexing requests come in. The cluster I am running receives documents from multiple systems. I do not have full control over how the documents are sent and would avoid having to touch everything that talks to it unless I really have to.

I am also aware of [index templates](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html) and the fact that [you can automatically set-up aliases on index creation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/aliases-ftw/) through them. However, as far as I understand, this does not solve my problem as you can't tell it to create an alias instead of an index.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you describe a nondeterministic behavior. Do a GET before you PUT to make sure that your index exists. If you're afraid that it'll put too much pressure on ES, you can set a caching layer that'll "ask" ES every minute if the index exists (once it does - it'll stop asking) and as long as it doesn't exist - use an alias. That said, I don't think that this is a "healthy" use of ES and you might want to consider changing the data-modeling you're using. For example - create all the relevant indexes before hand (it has nothing to do with kagillion shards).

Comment: GET before PUT with caching is the proper solution but unfortunately that would require me to change the indexing code in the client systems which is something I am trying to avoid. I might need to do that in the end if there's no way to automatically create aliases. I can't create the indices/aliases beforehand as I don't know exactly what buckets the indexers will want to put the data into.

Comment: You can prevent the index from being created, but then the clients will get an error. At least they have the option to change their code then. Explain them the proper way of doing it. But reading your question that might not be an option. Maybe a custom plugin can help you out here. Not sure though and for me it would not be the way to go. Teach the clients would be a better option if it is possible.